# WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 60 using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In my Java project I am using Selenium for web automation. I am using chromedriver v2.20 executable. First "ChromeDriverService" is initialised and that is used to create ChromeDriver like, "new ChromeDriver(service, capabilities);". Also I used BrowserMobProxy to capture all web requests.
In my test I navigate to some URLs multiple times, after each navigation driver implicitly waits for few seconds, then polls result. 
But while Execution it gives me timeout Exception.

In my research I came across solutions which are not working for me:

1. Instead of implicitlyWait use Thread.sleep
2. Replace new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), capabilities); by new ChromeDriver(service, capabilities);
3. After new ChromeDriver(...), wait for 1 sec using Thread.sleep(1000);

*Can anyone please tell me why this error occurs ? how to handle this ?*

**ShouldPostToServerTest.java:**

```
@Test 
public void setTest() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        nav();
        poll();
    }
}

private void nav() {
    String[] navTo = {"http://www.bestbuy.com","http://www.amazon.com"};
    for (int n = 0; n < 30 / navTo.length; n++) {
        for (String url : navTo) {
            chrome.navigateTo(url);
            chrome.waitFor(5000);
        }
    }
}

private void poll() {
    int pollInterval = 1000;
    int remaining = 120 * 1000;
    boolean found = false;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        if (found) // populateResult(), omitted for now.
            break;

        chrome.waitFor(pollInterval);
        remaining -= pollInterval;
    }
}
```

**Chrome.java:**

```
public void navigateTo(String url) {
    if (driver == null)
        return;

    driver.navigate().to(url); // TimeOut 
}
public void waitFor(long waitFor) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(waitFor, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    long remaining = waitFor - duration;
    if (remaining > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(remaining);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error stack trace**:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57086', transport: 'socket'
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 13817
Only local connections are allowed.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Vector smash protection is enabled.
Vector smash protection is enabled.
[723.497][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
[1323.497][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
```

**Exception:**

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot
>   determine loading status from timeout: Timed out receiving message
>   from renderer: 600.000   (Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.101)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124
>   (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux
>   3.19.0-28-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 1200.01 seconds
>   Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision:
>   '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09
>   13:08:06' System info: host: 'yogesh-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-28-generic',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_60' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.rgDfCi},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   hasTouchScreen=false, version=45.0.2454.101, platform=LINUX,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   a97aeb9a53ddd77e8edfac64019cc599  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:927)
>     at app.core.browsers.chrome.Chrome.navigateTo(Chrome.java:112)  at
>   app.core.extensions.tests.ShouldPostToServerTest.nav(ShouldPostToServerTest.java:58)
>     at
>   app.core.extensions.tests.ShouldPostToServerTest.setTest(ShouldPostToServerTest.java:49)

Comment: In my case if my window is getting closed due to some close button in application, i am running into this error. any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 4):

Your code runs fine. Might be you using outdated chrome driver. I suggest to use latest exe of chrome driver.

Comment: In very first line I have mentioned which version of chromedriver executable I am using. I think that is the latest.

Comment: **@pratapvaibhav19** thanks for efforts. But if you try to run it multiple times it will give you above exception. Also if you increase nav loop count for (int n = 0; n < 30 / navTo.length; n++) from 30 to 50. It will produce above exception.

Comment: try to do one thing- downgrade your chrome driver to version 2.12.301325(win 32)

Comment: In chrome 84 also I faced this  for a site which had a lot of widgets and iframes.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57086', transport: 'socket'
Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b) on port 13817
.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot
determine loading status from timeout: Timed out receiving message
from renderer: 600.000   (Session info: chrome=45.0.2454.101)  
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124
(035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 3.19.0-28-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 1200.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd10cf2c0560f637404c2d96164b67d9d67', time: '2015-10-09 13:08:06' System info: host: 'yogesh-ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-28-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_60' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though your *chromedriver=2.20* and *chrome=45.0* are compatable.
- But your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_60** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between *JDK v8u60* , *Selenium Client v'2.48.2* , *ChromeDriver v2.20* and the *Chrome Browser v45.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u241](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v80.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 80.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v80.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.16/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.